# Save terminal commands in "Run/Debug Configurations" in Phpstorm

Tags: cordova, ide, cmd, phpstorm

I'd like to be able to save certain terminal commands so that I can click run and it will run that command for me.

[image]

Currently I am using the terminal provided in phpstorm to run grunt commands. Ideally I'd like to be able to just click the play button and it will run the

```
 Phonegap run android
```

or any other commands for example.

I have phonegap set up, but without using the Android studio or eclipse. This way I can use my licensed Phpstorm with syntax highlighting as well.

Comment: No, you cannot do that as there is no support for configuration of such type (unless there is 3rd party plugin somewhere). The most obvious solutions for me: 1) write basic batch/shell scripts that will execute those munch of commands in one go 2) You are using PhpStorm, which assumes that you can use PHP. So -- write few Phing tasks and use them

Comment: you can also set up these commands/shell scripts as external tools to run them from menus

Comment: @lena How'd you manager to get that going then?

Comment: @Jamie, not sure I follow you... Do you have truoubles setting up external tools? If yes, what problems have you faced namely?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I couldn't work out how to save commands and would still love to. I have found this as the next best thing:

[image]

Open multiple terminals at once in Phpstorm.